# does webapp has 'elseif' or 'elif' in template tags

Tags: python, google-app-engine, if-statement

my code is :
Hello!~~~

```
{% if user %}
    <p>Logged in as {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}.</p>
{% elif openid_user%}
    <p>Hello, {{openid_user.nickname}}! Do you want to <a href="{{openid_logout_url}}">Log out?</p>
{% else %}
    <p><a href="/login?redirect={{ current_url }}">google Log in</a>.</p>
    <p><a href="/twitter">twitter Log in</a>.</p>
    <p><a href="/facebook">facebook Log in</a>.</p>
    <p><a href="{{openid_login_url}}">openid Log in</a>.</p>
    <iframe src="/_openid/login?continue=/"></iframe>
{% endif %}
```

the error is :

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'elif'
```

does not webapp has a 'else if ' ?

thanks

Comment: it is courteous to upvote—click the upward-facing arrow—answers that are helpful to you.

Comment: You've been a member of the site for 5 months and have a total of 6 upvotes and 5 downvotes.

Comment: Two of three tags mis-spelled.

Comment: @Adam: zjm1126 is lazy and sloppy. Don't except courteous behavior from him.

Comment: Django's template syntax is garbage. Very hard to use. Very unfriendly. Although it's already version 4.1, nothing changes...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`webapp` per se has no templates, but you can use Django templates - **by default**, those from back in [Django 0.96](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/#if) (as you see from the ancient docs I pointed to, that requires the nested `if` to be physically nested inside the `else` block).  You can use a more updated version of Django (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) for more details) by starting your Python code with

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.1')
```

but while this does give you a template language that's vastly improved in many ways, those improvements do *not* include an `elseif` or `elif` tag -- you *still* have to explicitly nest the secondary `if` inside the primary one's `else` branch.

Comment: `elif` is now supported. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Answer (score 17):

**Update**: [as Jeff Bauer says in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946826/does-webapp-has-elseif-or-elif-in-template-tags/2946849#comment15621678_2946849), Django 1.4 [provides an `elif` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#minor-features).

Original answer as follows:

---

[The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter04/#cn131) has this to say:

> There is no `{% elif %}`  tag. Use nested `{%  if %}` tags to accomplish the same thing:

So, you have to do

```
if
else
  if
  else
```

to achieve an if-elsif-else.

This is reflected in their [Design Philosophies](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/?from=olddocs#don-t-invent-a-programming-language):

> The goal is not to invent a programming language. The goal is to offer just enough programming-esque functionality, such as branching and looping, that is essential for making presentation-related decisions.

Comment: interesting. I always thought that GAE had full Jinja2 template support.

Comment: As of Django 1.4, templates now support the elif tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#minor-features

Answer (score 0):

There are also two Django Snippets that enable the 'elif' tag in the template language

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1572/

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2243/

Comment: How to use it. I mean shall we copy the code snippet and keep it in a file inside templatetags folder. And then ?? Could you please explain.